# Selectively delete cookies from CookieManager android

Tags: android, cookies

All the webviews in a app will use the same cookie manager. SO I want to do something like remove only a particular set of Cookies but not all of them.

I know that deleting all the cookies and setting the ones i want will work but i do not want that. Is there any way to do that?